# Can MySQL secondary member role high disk read affect primary member role performance?

Tags: mysql-8.0

We have a MySQL (8.0.27-commercial MySQL Enterprise Server - Commercial) topology of 3 servers, one with primary role (server01) and with two secondary role (server02 and server03).
For monitoring, we use Dynatrace and it shows the server03 with high throughput and IOPS (disk read operations). As disk reads became higher until somepoint the service went down.
The server01 (primary) and server02 metrics did not show high usage.

We have checked the storages for server03 and the host logs show no latency or disconnections.
Also checked mysql log and also show no problems or events.

Can a MySQL secondary role node affect primary role node as in this case?

For comparison i am sharing graph of server01 (primary) and server03 (secondary) about throughput and when the service went down.

Graph from Dynatrace of server01

[image: server01]

Graphs from Dynatrace of server03

[image: server03]